# How can I get the Title of a featureType of a WfsService using GeoTools

Tags: geotools

I'm connected to a WFS service using GeoTools library. It's pretty easy to get the `typeNames` of the available feature types:

```
        var dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connectionParameters);
        var typeNames = dataStore.getTypeNames();
```

What I expected to be quite easy too is to get the title of the available feature types. And indeed, they are present in the data structure you can retrieve via

```
        var info = dataStore.getInfo();
```

Screenshot of containing data shows name AND title are present:

[image]

Unfortunately the class the `CapabilitiesServiceInfo` lacks getters for capabilities. Does anybody know how to get the information which is obviously present but seems to be inaccessible? Is there another way to retrieve them (besides parsing the XML response manually)?

---

A MVE Ian Turton was asking for:

```
var url = "https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_dvg?ACCEPTVERSIONS=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities";

Map<String, Object> connectionParameters = new HashMap<>();
connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:LENIENT", true);
connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:USEDEFAULTSRS", true);
connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", url);

try
{
    var dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connectionParameters);

    // This is how I can retrieve the time names of the available feature types
    var featureTypeNames = dataStore.getTypeNames(); // will return a list containing "dvg:nw_dvg1_gem"
    // Looking at the WFS XML representation I this corresponds to the Name of the FeatureType in the FeatureTypeList:
    // (Excerp from the plain XML I get using the url from above in postman or just chrome browser)
    //      <FeatureTypeList>
    //        <Operations>
    //            <Operation>Query</Operation>
    //        </Operations>
    //        <FeatureType>
    //            <Name>dvg:nw_dvg1_gem</Name>
    //            <Title>DVG1 Kreisangehörige Kommunen und kreisfreie Städte</Title>
    // ...
    // ...

    // what I'm looking for are the titles of the available feature types
    // it would contain (among others) "DVG1 Kreisangehörige Kommunen und kreisfreie Städte"
    // what I'm looking for are the titles of the available feature types
    // it would contain (among others) "DVG1 Kreisangehörige Kommunen und kreisfreie Städte"
    // when you look into the object structure you get with wfsInfo you see getools has the information inside but seems to not offer a function
    // to accees it. An example of the structure of wfsInfo can be seen in the screenshot above).
    var wfsInfo = dataStore.getInfo();

    // This is (how Ian Turton said) how I would get the title of the service (but actually I'm not looking for it but the featureTypes titles)
    var theTitle = dataStore.getInfo().getTitle();
    // corresponting part in the XML message:
    //          <ows:ServiceIdentification>
    //           <ows:Title>WFS NW DVG</ows:Title>
    //          var theTitle = dataStore.getInfo().getTitle();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to connect to WFS service", e);
}
```

Comment: can you provide a MVE that shows what your problem is? From a quick look `dataStore.getInfo()` returns a `WFSServiceInfo` which has a `getTitle()` method from `ServiceInfo` - and looking at `CapabilitiesServiceInfo` there is a `getTitle` method implemented.

Comment: I'm looking for the titles of the service's feature types not the title of the service itself :-).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `WFSClient.getInfo(QName)` where the `QName` is the name of the feature type you are interested in (`dvg:nw_dvg1_gem`). You can access the client from a `WFSDatatstore.getWfsClient()`